# iText: How to set page events for footer accounting for page rotation?

Tags: itext

When creating a PDF from scratch, I'm trying to adapt this code

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104

specifically the onEndPage() function shown there, to set a footer using page events. The problem is in my application, some pages are Portrait and some Landscape, and I don't know how to implement a query in that function to determine the page rotation.

First, I got it working when all pages are portrait. Then I added some landscape pages and tried to modify it as shown below. I originally thought a quick-and-dirty solution would be simply to center the footer table by adding,

```
table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

but this didn't seem to have any effect (on landscape pages, the table is always aligned left on the long-edge of the paper). Then I tried to do a better solution by querying the page rotation, and based on its results, set the table columns to the correct widths, using,

```
if (???==90)
              table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{2.25f*K.PPI,1.195f*K.PPI,0.805f*K.PPI,2.25f*K.PPI,});  // add to 6.5"
            else
              table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{3.25f*K.PPI,1.195f*K.PPI,0.805f*K.PPI,3.25f*K.PPI,});  // add to 6.5"
```

but I'm not sure how to query the page rotation (as you can tell). Any help would be appreciated. My code is as follows.

```
class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
 /** The header text. */
 String footerLeft, footerRight;
 /** The template with the total number of pages. */
 PdfTemplate total;
 /** Flag indicating true for first page */
 Boolean firstPageFlag=true;
 ...
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
     if (firstPageFlag==false) {
        /** The footer font */
        FontFactory.register("/home/appFonts/Arial_Narrow.ttf", "arial_narrow");
        Font styleFooter = FontFactory.getFont("arial_narrow", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, K.TEXT_FOOTER_FONT_SIZE, Font.UNDEFINED, BaseColor.BLACK);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
        try {
            //table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER); // doesn't seem to have an effect for landscape pages
            if (how to query page rotation, or other method to evaluate whether page is landscape or portrait?)
              table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{2.25f*K.PPI,1.195f*K.PPI,0.805f*K.PPI,2.25f*K.PPI,});  // add to 6.5"
            else
              table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{3.25f*K.PPI,1.195f*K.PPI,0.805f*K.PPI,3.25f*K.PPI,});  // add to 8.5"
            table.setLockedWidth(true);
            table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(14);
            table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
            // col1, row1
            table.addCell(new Phrase(footerLeft, styleFooter));
            table.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
            // col2, row1
            table.addCell(new Phrase(String.format("page %d of", writer.getPageNumber()),styleFooter));
            // col3, row1
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(Image.getInstance(total));
            cell.setBorder(Rectangle.TOP);
            table.addCell(cell);
            // col4, row1
            table.addCell(new Phrase(footerRight, styleFooter));
            table.writeSelectedRows(0,-1,document.left(),document.bottom()-0.35f*K.PPI,writer.getDirectContent());
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
     } else
        firstPageFlag=false;
 }
...
}
```

Comment: You are mixing page events (used when creating PDFs *from scratch*) with `PdfReader` (used when manipulating *existing PDFs*). This is confusing people who want to answer your question (and probably confusing yourself). Please explain if you're creating a PDF from scratch (in which case you shouldn't use `PdfReader`) or based on an existing PDF (in which case you shouldn't use page events).

Comment: @ggkmath As an addendum to Bruno's comment: If you want to add headers and footers to an *existing* PDF, you might want to look at the second pass of the sample [TwoPasses.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=118). There you do have a `PdfReader` and can use your page rotation test.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is creating a PDF from scratch (not modifying an existing PDF). I modified the original posting to remove references to PdfReader.

Comment: Maybe you should still look at that [TwoPasses.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=118) sample and create your PDF in two passes, too, creating the document in the first and adding headers and footers in the second. If that is difficult (e.g. because of certain contextual information added to the header), you might want to look into the writer or document during `onStartPage`, they might carry the size information of the new page currently being created. Store these information in a member of your `HeaderFooter` and use them during `onEndPage`.

Comment: Well, the rectangle does not only have width (`getWidth`) and height (`getHeight`), it also has rotation (`getRotation`). If rotation is 0 or 180, the page is landscape iff width > height; otherwise, the page is landscape iff height > width. Or so I assume. (I'm rarely creating documents from scratch, normally I'm only post-processing them, so I'm not really into these details here.)

Comment: Thanks SO much @Bruno and @mkl, I've got a solution now. Using the latter approach, I've defined a variable `Boolean isPageRotated=false;` in `HeaderFooter` class, added an `onStartPage()` function to this class that retrieves the page size using `Rectangle pSize=document.getPageSize();` and another line to test it as `if (pSize.getRotation()==90) {}`. I then use `isPageRotated` in `onEndPage()` to determine how to set table columns. This works very well. Thank you for your comments. They really helped a lot. If you want to summarize as an answer to get full credit, please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Summarizing the solution developed in the comments to the question*

As @Bruno initially stated correctly, the original attempt of the OP was

> mixing page events (used when creating PDFs from scratch) with `PdfReader` (used when manipulating existing PDFs).

It would have been possible to actually use the OP's `PdfReader` centric test for landscape by switching to a two-pass architecture as used in the sample [TwoPasses.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=118) but the OP preferred a one-pass approach.

For this one-pass approach the original `HeaderFooter` page event listener was extended to also store the page dimension information upon page construction. This was done by overriding `onStartPage()` to retrieve the page size using

```
Rectangle pSize=document.getPageSize();
```

and storing its relevant information in a member variable of the listener. Eventually this information now is used in `onEndPage()` to determine how to set table columns.

In case of the OP's processes, landscape pages are created by means of rotation. Thus the relevant information in his case was whether

```
(pSize.getRotation()==90)
```

is `true` (landscape) or not (portrait). In general the whole `Rectangle` including both its rotation and its dimension values would have to be stored and eventually be used to determine the desired header and footer locations.